# How to Handle FORM_URL_ENCODED to POJO with Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I can't seem to find any information on how to have Quarkus convert incoming URL_FORM_ENCODED requests into a POJO.

The documentation says I can annotate each parameter in my receiving method with the @RestForm parameter. But, in the case where we have a lot of form params that would mean I have to add each parameter to my method signature.

I tried simply doing something like:

```java
public class FormStuff {
   @RestForm
   public String title;

   ....More fields
}
```

and then in my receiving method I have:

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void save(FormStuff stuff) {
  log.info("Got Stuff! {}", stuff);
}
```

However, when I call this from my webpage I always get a `415 Unsupported MediaType`

BUT! If I change my signature to:

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void save(@RestForm title) {
  log.info("Got Stuff! {}", title);
}
```

The request goes through and I see the title field print out.

Does Quarkus support converting Forms to POJO like it does for MultiPart forms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void save(@BeanParam FormStuff stuff) {
  log.info("Got Stuff! {}", stuff);
}
```

`@BeanParam` is a JAX-RS standard annotation that users can use to gather multiple HTTP params into a POJO.

Comment: thanks..do you know if Quarkus supports the ParamConverterProvider when using @BeanParam? It doesn't appear to be using my converter I have registered to convert java.util.Date params.

When I leave in my Date fields I got a `400 Bad Request` but then I comment them out the request comes in. 

Inside my POJO I have the date as `@FormParam("expireDate") Date expireDate;`

Comment: I am also using RestEasy Reactive in my project. I see something like https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/21664 but I'm not getting that far. My converter isn't even being called.

Comment: I did more experimenting and it seems it is something with `quarkus-renarde` framework causing `java.util.Date` to not be processed on startup by the jax-rs runtime. I put a print statement in my provider to see what types it checks and WITHOUT renarde including in my dependencies I see the provider looking for a `java.util.Date` converter. BUT if I put back the renarde dependency it stops looking for `java.util.Date`.

I need to use Renarde for our conversion project to Quarkus. I guess I'll file a bug with them.